# If image open with... else open with?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, image

I was just wondering if there is anyone out here that knows how to write a code how to check if item is an image then open with Windows image preview else open With Build in Media player.

Code is like this :

```
private bool listbox3job()
{
    AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer axWmp = wfh.Child as AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer;
    WMPLib.IWMPPlaylist playlist = axWmp.newPlaylist("myPlaylist", string.Empty);
    DateTime? start = starttid2.Value;
    DateTime? end = sluttid2.Value;
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

    if (start == null || end == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if (now >= start.Value && now <= end.Value)
    {
        foreach (var selected in listBox3.Items)
        {
            string s = selected.ToString();
            if (listBox3Dict.ContainsKey(s))
            {
    if (extentions.Contains(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(s).ToUpperInvariant()))
    {
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "rundll32.exe";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"C:\WINDOWS\System32\shimgvw.dll,ImageView_Fullscreen " + listBox3Dict[s];
        process.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(7000);
        {
            exit();
        }
    }
    else
    {
                WMPLib.IWMPMedia temp = axWmp.newMedia(listBox3Dict[s]);  
                playlist.appendItem(temp);
                axWmp.settings.setMode("loop", true);
                axWmp.settings.autoStart = true;
                axWmp.currentPlaylist = playlist; 
    }
            }
        }
                return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Windows itself uses the file extension, and catches any errors thrown by the selected handler.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens
Yes but "Mediaplayer.URL = (listBox4Dict[s]);" is an built in media player so I need a if statement solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are

```
 public static List<string> extentions = new List<string> { ".JPG", ".JPE", ".BMP", ".GIF", ".PNG" };

private void Open()
{

    foreach (var selected in listBox4.Items)
    {
        string s = selected.ToString();

        if (listBox4Dict.ContainsKey(s))
        {
            if (extentions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(s).ToUpperInvariant()))
            {
                Process process = new Process();
                process.StartInfo.FileName = "rundll32.exe";
                process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"C:\WINDOWS\System32\shimgvw.dll,ImageView_Fullscreen " +listBox4Dict[s];
                process.Start();
                process.WaitForExit();
                while (!process.HasExited)
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
            else
            {
                Mediaplayer.URL = (listBox4Dict[s]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code looks great but the image still launches via the "Mediaplayer.URL = (listBox4Dict[s]);"

Comment: no check your code because it runs correctly or debug to see why is that

Comment: or maybe your images Extension is not in the list above

Comment: Check my first post again, edited the code
The image was .jpg extension btw.
Thnx for helping me!

Comment: nvm! used GetFileNameWithoutExtension on the listbox.
Thanks for help ! :)

Comment: These are rundll32.exe paramters ImageView_Fullscreen
ImageView_FullscreenA
ImageView_FullscreenW
ImageView_PrintTo
ImageView_PrintToA
ImageView_PrintToW
ImageView_fullscreenW
DllCanUnloadNow
DllGetClassObject you can use one of them